# Change which python installation my apache local server is using

Tags: python, macos, apache, cgi

I have two python installations, one at /usr/bin/env and one through Enthought at /Library/Enthought/User/bin/python. The enthought installation has a library that I would like to use in a website that I've inherited from a former coworker.

I set up a local server through apache on my Mac OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite). I configured httpd.conf and my user configuration file inside of the website folder to execute cgi and py files.

However, when I try to run my coworker's python scripts through the server, it seems to use the installation without the package I need (/usr/bin/env). I tried changing the shebang at the top of the script from:

'#!/usr/bin/env python'
to
'#!/Library/Enthought/User/bin/ python'

but that gives me an internal service error (500).

One thing I was able to do was to create a symlink using this command:
'sudo ln -s /Library/Enthought/User/bin/python /usr/bin/python'

Now his script can run and has no trouble finding the right python package. However, I'd like to understand why changing the shebang isn't enough. Why does the server still access the /usr/bin/env python distribution?

A subquestion:
Lastly, I created my own test script in the meantime, but I get an Internal Service Error (500) no matter what the shebang is. This script is in the same folder as his script. Why can't this script run?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"
print "Hello."
print "</body></html>"
```

Thanks! I hope this question was clear. This is my first experience with web servers, so please correct me if I made any terminology mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

The shebang life you quote doesn't work because of the space at the end. `/usr/bin/env` is a program, and `python` is the argument, the name of the program it's supposed to look for. Remove the space from your new shebang and you will be running the Python interpreter directly. There's no need to provide it with an argument.

As to why the other script isn't working, I can only guess that you haven't made it executable, since I can't find any other reason for its failure (but this *is* a guess).

Comment: Perfect, thanks holdenweb. I didn't realize /usr/bin/env is a program. Would you mind lending some insight into the subquestion as well? Why does that test script with the correct shebang (no need to load the python package here) give an "Internal Service Error"?

Answer (score -1):

Your second print statement does not have an argument.  Try changing it from `print` to `print "\n"`.

**EDIT**

Try the following script with the appropriate shebang line prepended and, as holdenweb says, make sure it has execute permissions for the right user.  Another issue I have run into in the past is with line terminations.  If you have the "od" utility, run "`od -c <filename>`" on the command line to do an octal dump for your new file and the existing, working file.  That way, you can see if the files end with the same line termination("\r\n" or "\n").

```
import cgi
print "HTTP/1.0 Status: 200 OK"
print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print "<html><head>"
print "</head><body>"
print "Hello."
print "</body></html>"
```

Note the addition of `print "HTTP/1.0 Status: 200 OK"`. Other than that...I am out of suggestions.

Comment: That would print a second newline. `print` output always terminates with a newline unless there's a dangling comma on the statement

Comment: @holdenweb It still fixes the issue.

Comment: Hm, that didn't work for me, apandit, but thanks for the suggestion! Could you recommend a better test script to try?

Comment: @apandit: the HTTP headers are terminated by a blank line (which is to say  the end-of-line terminating the last header, immediately followed by another. As the poster reports, it doesn't fix the error.

Comment: @js9 Please let me know if the suggestions in the edit above work.

Comment: Still no luck. The "od" utility showed that there is a \n at the end of the file. I opened it in vim though and in the Mac TextEdit GUI and I don't see how to remove the \n, since there's no line after the last " key.